# Infinity page loading when host ASP Net Core application in IIS

Tags: azure, iis, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, single-page-application

Good day, I have an error with my **ASP.Net Core** application. I have installed two ASP.NET Core web sites on **dnx451** framework on **Windows Server 2012** in the **Azure Cloud**.

When I navigate to them in browser, they are infinitely loading. Before it happened I installed `HttpPlatformHandler` because of the following error, but right now I don't see anything exception infinite loading.

Error that I see before install `HttpPlatformHandler`.

[image]

Also,

1. Application is running successfully from Visual Studio and dnx web.
2. Insert logs in the startup (send emails), no logs where created.
3. Loading page:

[image]

Please help, thanks.

Comment: Can you share your `Startup.cs` and `project.json` ?

Comment: And your web.config.

Comment: for project1: web.config [web config](http://pastebin.com/6KSF50Tf) startup.cs [startup](http://pastebin.com/8VHrd6D7) [project.json](http://pastebin.com/wk8ABXFJ)

Comment: for project 2: [startup.cs](http://pastebin.com/eiXFjGYk), [web.config](http://pastebin.com/5D7CJUc8), [project.json](http://pastebin.com/9N0qZzZc)

Comment: @blowdart it's good idea but url rewriteng only in one project and chrome understand this error

Comment: @agua-from-mars please, see my comments

Comment: Also note they replaced HttpPlatformHandler with AspNetCoreModule: https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/164

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short Answer

Infinite loading occurs when IIS cannot find dnx.exe. That happens when the publish fails to include runtimes in its output.

## Solution

Use the `--runtime` flag when publishing.

```
cd Project01
dnvm use 1.0.0-rc1-final -runtime clr   <------ Set the active runtime.
dnu build
dnu publish --runtime active            <------ Use the runtime flag.
```

The runtime flag provides the name or full path of the runtime folder to include, or `active` for the current runtime on the PATH.

If that still doesn't include the `runtimes` directory in the publish output, then upgrade to the most recent release of `dnu`, because there is a bug in older versions.

## Explanation

Infinite loading occurs when IIS cannot find `dnx.exe`. That happens when the publish fails to include runtimes in its output.

Here is how to check whether a missing `dnx.exe` is causing the infinite loading problem.

1. Publish your web application (e.g. `dnu publish`.)
2. Navigate to the publish output directory (e.g. `bin\output\`.)
3. Make sure `approot\runtimes\..\..\dnx.exe` is present.

Here are the key files that the publish output must contain. I've omitted some other important files to for clarity.

```
\Project01\bin\output\
    approot
        packages         
        runtimes <--------------------------------This is sometimes missing.
            dnx-clr-win-x64.1.0.0-rc1-final
                bin
                    dnx.exe <---------------------IIS needs to find this.
        src              
        global.json      
        web              
        web.cmd              
    logs
    wwwroot <-------------------------------------IIS Physical Path
```

External Links

- https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/364#issuecomment-148567294
- https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/2858